# Неравномерный шаг на оси X в гистограмме

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы шаг оси Ox до определённого значения был маленьким, а после - большим?

Моя ситуация: строю гистограмму, где большинство данных лежат в небольшом интервале [0-100], но есть некоторые экстремальные значения (1500,2000 и т.п.), поэтому ось Ox расширяется и получаю сливающиеся высокие столбики в начале, большой пропуск и очень маленькие столбики в районе экстремальных значений. Надо, чтобы вначале столбики были видны (например, с шагом 5), а потом диапазон [100-2000] составлял один столбик.

Использую метод `plt.hist()`.

Скрин текущего поведения для:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1000, 2000]
bins = [1, 2, 4, 5, 1000, 2000]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите пожалуйста в вопросе тот код который у вас есть на данный момент - попытку решения и пример входных данных. Из формулировки вопроса не понятно как именно вы хотите строить гистограммы - какие должны быть диапазоны (`bins`)

Comment: @MaxU ну я же написал всё: много чисел из диапазона [1-100] должны попасть в большое количество bins (с шагом 5 получается 20 штук), а потом 1 bin для диапазона [100-2000] для экстремальных значений

Comment: @MaxU входные данные очень большие, можно сгенерировать случайно из [1-100] 10000 значений и 10 значений из [1000-2000]

Comment: @MaxU код на данный момент `plt.hist(x, bins)`, где bins - фиксированное число, x - все данные в list

Comment: @MaxU добавил скрин с примером, надо чтобы левые колонки были нормально различимы, а правые не такие широкие

Comment: вам решение с использованием Pandas и Numpy подойдет?

Comment: @MaxU да, спасибо

Comment: значения из диапазона [1500,2000] должны попадать в одну корзину?

Comment: @MaxU не обязательно в одну, важно чтобы суммарная ширина получившихся правых столбцов не сужала важные левые столбцы, как происходит на скрине

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# randomly generated data
a = np.random.randint(101, size=10000)
b = np.random.randint(1500, 2001, size=20)
x = pd.Series(np.concatenate((a,b)))

# custom binning ...    
bins = np.concatenate((np.arange(0, 105, 5), [1500, 2001]))
labels = np.concatenate((np.arange(5, 105, 5).astype(str), ['100-1500', '1500-2000']))
r = x.groupby(pd.cut(x, bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)).size()

# plotting ...    
r[r>0].plot.bar(rot=0, figsize=(12, 4), grid=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]